# jQuery UI autocomplete - selectfirst extension

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the jQuery UI autocomplete 1.8.6 and need to include the selectfirst functionality into this. I downloaded the selectfirst extension js from 
https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.selectFirst.js

Can someone tell me how to use this extension with the core autocomplete functionality? If I try to add the selectFirst option to the autocomplete widget, it gives error that it is not a valid property.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get this working by simply

1. Adding the reference code to my page
2. Including selectFirst: true in the options for the autocomplete

There is a demo here:

http://dev.nemikor.com/jquery-ui-extensions/autocomplete/selectFirst.html